# Call jquery function inside Angularjs controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an angularjs controller. I am calling a restful webservice.

```
app.controller('ordersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {

$scope.fetchOrders = function () {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/blah/blah";
    // $http({method: 'POST', url : url})

    var data = $.param({"title": "kuldeep"});

    $http({method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
}
```

I want to submit form data. So using jquery to convert object to form data. But getting the error :

```
$ is not defined
at Scope.$scope.fetchOrders (ordersModule.js:34)
```

What should I do to inject jquery inside controller. Or any alternate to make form data will be appreciated.

Comment: You should load `jquery.js` on DOM prior to `angular.js`

Comment: @Vineet It did not help.

Comment: @Vineet Why before? The application starts **after** the page has been loaded.

Comment: @KuldeepYadav Why you need to use jquery in your case. If you clear your scenario I can help you much in deep

Comment: @Rakeschand It has nothing to do with `angular.element`. The OP calls `$.` not `$(`.

Comment: @Rakeschand 
tried this : var data = angular.element.param({"title": "kuldeep"});

angular.js:13920 TypeError: angular.element.param is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.fetchOrders (ordersModule.js:34)

Comment: @Vineet I have a jersey restful api on server side 

    public List<Order> readOrders(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
                                  \@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                                  \@FormParam("title") String title){

I want to call this using angular's $http service. So Basically I don't know how to make form data to be posted.

Comment: Did you try `$http.post(url, data, callBackFunction)` ?

Comment: Either jQuery is not included or it's included with `.noConflict()`. Or `$` has simply been overwritten.

Comment: @Vineet My question is how to convert my data object to FormParam data. And I think there is not much difference between my way to post data and yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need to Use Jquery param function use angular params serializer:

**$httpParamSerializerJQLike**
Alternative $http params serializer that follows jQuery's param() method logic. The serializer will also sort the params alphabetically.

```
$http({
  url: myUrl,
  method: 'GET',
  params: myParams,
  paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'
});


.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

})
```

**OR** read Angular API Doc: == Click Me > [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)